# How to install Nvidia CUDA driver on AWS ec2 instance?

Tags: nvidia, aws, gpu-driver

I am using AWS instance but Nvidia CUDA driver is not install there. I need help to install Nvidia CUDA driver on ec2 install.

The Ubuntu version is 18.04 and the instance is GPU based. The graphics card is nvidia t4. I am using the g46nxlarge instance.

Answer (score 5):

The `g4dn.xlarge` EC2 instances are not your typical virtual machines, as there are some unique features that enable the machine to interface directly with a dedicated video card. For this reason, there are dedicated AMIs for [Deep Learning](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/search/results/?searchTerms=deep+learning&AMI_INSTANCE_TYPE=g4dn.xlarge&filters=AMI_INSTANCE_TYPE), [virtual workstations](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/search/results/?searchTerms=NVIDIA+Quadro&AMI_INSTANCE_TYPE=g4dn.xlarge&filters=AMI_INSTANCE_TYPE), and [gaming](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/search/results/?searchTerms=gaming&AMI_INSTANCE_TYPE=g4dn.xlarge&filters=AMI_INSTANCE_TYPE). However, if you insist on starting from scratch, Amazon has [provided a step-by-step](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-nvidia-driver.html) that shows you how to get the CUDA drivers installed on your instance.

The gist goes like this:

1. Visit the [NVIDIA Driver Search page](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/Find.aspx) to search for the appropriate driver package for your installation:
   [image: NVIDIA Driver Search Results]
2. Install the driver using the steps from [NVIDIA's Data Center Documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/tesla/tesla-installation-notes/index.html), not forgetting the myriad [post-installation steps](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#post-installation-actions)

Given the number of steps and ways the manual installation can go wrong, you *might* want to start with the pre-built AMIs first and then rebuild with a custom installation (if required) later.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works for Ubuntu 18.04, but I tested this approach on Ubuntu 22.04. Nevertheless I post this answer in case other people who are using 22.04 want to do the same thing.

I tried several blogs on the Internet and finally I managed to install nvidia driver by following this blog: https://www.linuxcapable.com/install-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-linux/ (I followed the section 1, 2, and 3)

During this process, I purged all existing nvidia things and then using
`sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`. Then `nvidia-smi` worked for me.

I tested this approach on EC2 type p2.xlarge (with Tesla K80) and p3.2xlarge (with Tesla V100), both worked.

OS: Ubuntu 22.04 (x86_64)

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1) pre-installed drivers e.g. "AWS Deep Learning Base GPU AMI (Ubuntu 20.04)"**

This AMI is documented at: https://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/aws-deep-learning-base-gpu-ami-ubuntu-20-04/ and can be found on the AWS EC2 web UI Launch instance by searching for "gpu" under the "Quickstart AMIs" section (their search is terrible btw). I believe it is maintained by Amazon.

I have tested it on a `g5.xlarge`, documented at: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/g5/ which I believe is currently the most powerful single Nvidia GPU machine available (Nvidia A10G) as of December 2023. Make sure to use a US region as they are cheaper there, `us-east-1` (North Virginia) was one of the cheapest when I checked, at 1.006 USD / hour, so a negligible cost for most people in a developed country. Just make sure to shutdown the VM each time to not keep paying!!!

Another working alternative is `g4dn.xlarge`, which is the cheapest GPU machine at 0.526 USD / hour on `us-east-1` and runs an Nvidia T4, but I don't think there's much point in it as it is just half the price of the most powerful GPU choice, so why not just go for the most powerful one which which might save you some of your precious time by making such interactive experiments faster? This one should only be a consideration when optimizing deployment costs.

Also, to get access to `g5.xlarge`, first you have to request your vCPU limit to be increased to 4 as per: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68347900/you-have-requested-more-vcpu-capacity-than-your-current-vcpu-limit-of-0 since the GPU machines all seem to require at least 4 vCPUs, it is supremely annoying.

Once you finally get the instance and the image, running:

```
nvidia-smi
```

just works and returns:

```
Tue Dec 19 18:43:59 2023       
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.104.12             Driver Version: 535.104.12   CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA A10G                    On  | 00000000:00:1E.0 Off |                    0 |
|  0%   18C    P8               9W / 300W |      4MiB / 23028MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                           |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This means the drivers are working, and from then on I managed run several software that use the GPU and watch `nvidia-smi` show the GPU usage go up.

The documentation page also links to: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dlami/latest/devguide/gs.html which is a guide on the so called "AWS Deep Learning AMI" (DLAMI) which appears to be a selection of deep learning AMI variants by AWS, though unfortunately many of the ones documented there use Amazon Linux (RPM-based) rather than Ubuntu.

A sample AWS CLI that launches it is:

```
aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-095ff65813edaa529 --count 1 --instance-type g5.xlarge \
  --key-name <yourkey> --security-group-ids sg-<yourgroup>
```

**Option 2) install the drivers yourself on the base Ubuntu image "Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS (HVM)"**

This option adds extra time to the installation, but it has the advantage of giving you a newer Ubuntu and greater understanding of what the image contains. Driver installation on Ubuntu 22.04 was super easy, so this is definitely a viable option.

Just pick the first Ubuntu AMI Amazon suggests when launching an instance and run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-510 nvidia-utils-510
sudo reboot
```

and from there on `nvidia-smi` and everything else just works on `g5.xlarge`.

Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63689325/how-to-activate-the-use-of-a-gpu-on-aws-ec2-instance

Answer (score 0):

In case there are other readers with the same question, there is an official document to get GPU and CUDA installed on a GPU-based instance [here](https://canonical-aws.readthedocs-hosted.com/en/latest/aws-how-to/instances/install-nvidia-drivers/)